# why is my web browser not sending cookies when I click a link, but it sends them just fine when I type in the url

Tags: google-chrome, http, go, firefox, cookies

I am creating a web application in Golang/HTML. I am implementing registration, sessions, email verification, and login.

My code works, however I have noticed some strange browser behavior. When the user registers for the first time, my application will send them an email containing a link with a unique nonce (number used once) in the url. This is to ensure that the user is able to receive email from us at that address and "verify their email", as is standard practice on many web applications.

```
Please click the following link to verify your account: http://localhost:8080/verify-email/55c17d2c
```

I noticed that when I receive this email, if I click on the link in the email, the browser will open the link in a new tab as expected, however, it will not send any cookies on requests associated with that tab.

But when I copy and paste the link into a new tab manually and press enter, it sends the cookies just fine. What gives? is this some sort of undocumented security feature?  What should I do about this?

I used https://github.com/six-ddc/httpflow  to capture a log of the HTTP requests and responses going between my web browser and my server application.  I have two separate logs, one of them captured a registration flow where i clicked the link, and the other one captured a registration flow where i copy and pasted the link into a new tab.

Log where link in email was clicked: [https://paste.cyberia.club/~forest/2f3fce7dcc71fc095341eeaefb33f20883c79886](https://paste.cyberia.club/%7Eforest/2f3fce7dcc71fc095341eeaefb33f20883c79886)

Log where link was copy and pasted from email into url bar: [https://paste.cyberia.club/~forest/0623f76cfee339e91d2213dd8f4c7710c6fa2797](https://paste.cyberia.club/%7Eforest/0623f76cfee339e91d2213dd8f4c7710c6fa2797)

Please note that I tried this on firefox and google chrome, I also tried it with a real domain and https certificate, got the same behavior in all browsers and setups.

---

Here are my constraints:

I want the application to work fine with javascript disabled, however, I'm open to javascript-based solutions if they are simple, secure, and make the site more enjoyable to use. For example, I am using a javascript that hashes passwords client side before sending to the server for login. But if javascript is disabled, the raw password will be sent.

I don't want the user to have to log in again after they click the link to verify their email address.

I don't want the link in the email address to represent a "free pass" into the user's account. I want to require the user to be already logged in (or somehow otherwise authenticated) before they can verify their email address. For example, if someone steals that email and clicks that link before the intended user does, I don't want the email thief to be able to take over the account.

Comment: The question was about the browser behavior, not the web application behavior. the web application was behaving just fine. We can tell, because we can see in the httpflow logs that it is responding as intended when a valid request is given.

 I simply didn't understand why the browser was doing what it was doing.

Answer (score 11):

OOPS I just figured this out, I wanted `Lax` SameSite policy on my cookies:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#SameSite_attribute

> It takes three possible values: Strict, Lax, and None. With Strict, the cookie is sent only to the same site as the one that originated it; Lax is similar, except that cookies are sent when the user navigates to the cookie's origin site, for example, by following a link from an external site;

Comment: thanks god for this, was driving me bananas