# HttpContext Sessions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, session, swagger, httpcontext

The email is being sent correctly but when I am trying to register the var email in the registering endpoint is empty, so I can't register. Why can't that variable get the Email from the session?
btw when I try to execute [HttpGet("getcodes")] funtion I get all of them in that function. but in Register endpoint every var that is from sessions is empty. Why does it happen? and What Can I do to fix this?

```
    [HttpGet("send-email-otp/{email}")]
    public IActionResult Sendmail(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Email address cannot be null or empty.", nameof(email));
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string otpCode = rnd.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("OTPCode", otpCode);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Email", email);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("OTPTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        SendEmail(email, "Your OTP code", $"Your OTP code is {otpCode}");

        return Ok();
    }
    
    

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Register([FromBody] RegisterDto registerDto)
    {
        string email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");
        if (await UserExist(registerDto.Email.ToLower())) return BadRequest("Email is taken, use other name");
        if (registerDto.Email != email) return BadRequest("You need to verify YOUR email");
        // Check if OTP code is valid
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registerDto.Otp))
        {
            return Ok("EmptyOTP");
        }
        string sessionOTP = HttpContext.Session.GetString("OTPCode");
        string sessionTimeString = HttpContext.Session.GetString("OTPTime");


        if (sessionOTP != registerDto.Otp)
        {
            return Ok(sessionOTP);
        }

        DateTime sessionTime;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(sessionTimeString, out sessionTime))
        {
            return Ok("False"); ;
        }

        if ((DateTime.Now - sessionTime).TotalMinutes > 30)
        {
            return Ok("Expired");
        }

        // OTP code is valid and not expired, clear session data
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("OTPCode");
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("Email");
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("OTPTime");



        HttpContext.Session.Remove("Email");

        using var hmac = new HMACSHA512();

        var user = new Client
        {
            Firstname = registerDto.Firstname.ToLower(),
            Lastname = registerDto.Lastname.ToLower(),
            Idnumber = registerDto.Idnumber,
            Email= registerDto.Email.ToLower(),
            PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registerDto.Password)),
            PasswordSalt = hmac.Key
        };

        await _context.Clients.AddAsync(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new UserDto { Username = user.Firstname, Token = _tokenService.CreateToken(user) };
    }

    private async Task<bool> UserExist(string email)
    {
        return await _context.Clients.AnyAsync(x => x.Email == email.ToLower());
    }
    private static void SendEmail(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("lukashekelashvili@gmail.com", "Clinic");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(email);
        const string fromPassword = "bnatgrawbmauhjed";
        const string smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = smtpServer,
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("getcodes")]
    public IActionResult GetCodes()
    {
        var code = HttpContext.Session.GetString("OTPCode");
        var time = HttpContext.Session.GetString("OTPTime");
        var email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email");
        var final = (code + " " + time + " " + email);
        return Ok(final);
    }
```

Comment: IActionResult is the body of a HTTP message. HttpGet is used to get the items in the body.  You have MIME attachments where each Mime message starts with two dashes on a new line.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  It looks like the attachments are HTML and you are extracting tags in the HTML.  I think you are using POST instead of GET.  Should be : HttpGet("register")

Comment: Are you accessing the register endpoint by clicking a link in the email sent? I assume your email client (for your protection) cleans out session cookies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675627/why-is-my-web-browser-not-sending-cookies-when-i-click-a-link-but-it-sends-them  - seems like the same issue

Comment: No I am sending OTP 6 digit code. When I do it all from swagger everythings okay It works well, but when I am sending data from Angular variable that gets data from Session is null.